# Shrinking a Stein open set to get a domain with smooth strongly pseudoconvex boundary.

Tags: analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

In *Demailly's Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry*, prop.4.1 Chapter III, he states that

> a)*$T$ has non zero bidimension (p,p) (i.e. degree of $T < 2n$, where $T$ is a closed positive current.)*
>
> b)*$X$ is covered by a family of Stein open sets $\Omega \subset \subset X$ whose boundaries $\partial \Omega$ do not intersect $L(u) \cap \mathrm{Supp} T$*
>
> *Then the current $uT$ has locally finite mass in X*

At the beginning of the proof, he asserts that by shrinking $\Omega$ slightly, we may assume that $\Omega$ has a smooth strongly pseudoconvex boundary. But how can the shrinking be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shrink $\Omega$ to be small enough so that it looks like a ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Such a thing has a smooth strongly pseudoconvex boundary.

Comment: This works well for $L(u)\cap \mathrm{Sup} T$ being discrete. And I come up with an answer when $\Omega$ is relatively compact. In this case we can find a smooth strictly plurisubharmonic exhaustion $\psi$ and let $\Omega_M = \{ \psi < M\}$. For $M$ great enough it must contain $L(u)\cap \mathrm{Sup} T$. The remainning question is whether the boundary of $\Omega_M$ is smooth.

Comment: For $\partial \Omega_M$ being smooth, note that every singular point of $\psi$ is a local minimum due to the strict plurisubharmonicity of $\psi$ and these points must not have accumulated points. But $\Omega_M$ is relatively compact in $\Omega$. Therefore there is atmost countably many $M$ s.t. $\{\psi = M \} = \partial \Omega_M$ which contains singular points of $\psi$. For $M$ other than those, $\partial \Omega_M$ is smooth.

Comment: For more general cases, I have no idea. Especially when $\Omega_M$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$. I don't know what does Demailly mean by 'Stein open set'.

Comment: I believe when Demailly says a 'Stein open set', he actually means a relatively compact set in $\mathbb{C}^n$. In the proof he uses lots of compact properties.

Comment: This might not be an appropriate answer but doesn't the symbol $\Omega\subset\subset X$ means the closure of $\Omega$ is compact in $X$?